# Mono cecil SaveSymbols(); in ver- 0.9.5.0

Tags: .net, mono.cecil

There was a AssemblyDefinition.MainModule.SaveSymbols(); 
But in version  0.9.5.0, how we can save a .pdb file before saving an AssemblyDefinition.

***//Here to add the command for save the .pdb file***

AssemblyDefinition.Write(***_***);

Comment: I just knew that it's SymbolWriterProvider to be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first need a copy of the `Mono.Cecil.Pdb.dll` assembly and then add a reference to that assembly from your application.

Code wise you do:

```
var parameters = new WriterParameters ();
parameters.SymbolWriterProvider = new Mono.Cecil.Pdb.PdbWriterProvider ();
assembly.Write ("myassembly.dll", parameters);
```